# I changed my system language in Ubuntu 16.04 and cannot login after reboot

Tags: login, keyboard-layout, language-support

I  changed my system language to Geez, an Ethiopian language, and I was using it.  But I forgot to reset or change the language setting to English when I logged out.

My intention was to use Geez one time only. Now  I cannot login after rebooting. The language switch keyboard shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does not switch the language on the login screen. My password is not recognized now because the Geez layout is being used and my password is English. I tried many things through GRUB shell.

I tried to change the language setting using Grub.  I  tried to change, I changed to `LANG = en_US.UTF-8` which was `LANG=am_ET.UTF-8`, `LC_ALL=C`, `LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8` which was `ET`. Most of the environment variables changed to `US` from `ET`.   I checked by `echo $LANG` and it shows the change. But when I reboot the language never change. I am believing the problem is caused after I changed the language.  The desktop is  Gnome.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please advise us, specifically, exactly what you tried through GRUB shell, and the result. Specificity is essential in troubleshooting.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] to explain ***what** exactly* you changed ***where** exactly*? What's the output of `locale` and the content of `/etc/default/keyboard` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (for long listings you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and add the link to your question)? Thanks.